# Jenkinsfile : Run a task in all Agents with same label

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to run a purticular task in the Jenkins pipeline in all Agents with same label. I got below code for this purpose. But it is not working as expected.
It only runs in the first slave with label "my_label" and then exit. I need to run the job on all Jenkins Slaves with this label.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```css
def labels=["my_label"] def builders=[:] for (x in labels) {
  def label=x builders[label]= {
    node(label) {
      // build steps that should happen on all nodes go here
      // Step 4
      stage('Run deployment on all agents in the given environment') {
        sh "echo Run deployment" sh "echo release_version = ${params.release_version}" sh "echo environment = ${params.environment}"
      }
    }
  }
}

parallel builders
```

Thanks,
Arun S

Answer (score 2):

I found this code which does what you ask for. However you need to uncheck 'sandbox'

```
// The script triggers PayloadJob on every node.
// It uses Node and Label Parameter plugin to pass the job name to the payload job.
// The code will require approval of several Jenkins classes in the Script Security mode
def branches = [:]
def names = nodeNames()
for (int i=0; i<names.size(); ++i) {
  def nodeName = names[i];
  // Into each branch we put the pipeline code we want to execute
  branches["node_" + nodeName] = {
    node(nodeName) {
      echo "Triggering on " + nodeName
    }
  }
}

// Now we trigger all branches
parallel branches

// This method collects a list of Node names from the current Jenkins instance
@NonCPS
def nodeNames() {
  return jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.nodes.collect { node -> node.name }
}
```